# Correct definition of proper divisor.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, definition

Similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26024/what-is-the-difference-between-divisors-and-proper-divisors) was previously asked on these topic. Also, [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperDivisor.html) has the same definition as the question that the proper divisors of a number are the divisors excluding the number itself.

But [this site](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-number-of-proper-divisors-of-displaystyle2p6q15r-is/) has excluded $1$, too, from the number of proper divisors. Same [here](https://www.askiitians.com/maths/permutation-and-combination.html) (in the section "Problems Based on Number Theory"). In my maths textbook "Objective Mathematics Vol.1" by R.D. Sharma [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFHCn.jpg) illustration is given which is same as these two.

My question is simple: Who is correct?

Comment: I would say it is more common to allow $1$ as a proper divisor (In fact, I am a little surprised that anyone would disallow $1$).  Still, in a cases where a term can be used informally, it may be best to define your meaning in context.

Comment: Either definition could be correct. E.g. when you talk about perfect numbers, it's more convinient to include $1$. So it depends on what you need the proper divisors for.

Comment: The MathWorld article cited also states "To make matters even more confusing, the proper divisor is often defined so that -1 and 1 are also excluded." Thus, there are several possible definitions of proper divisor depending on the specific use case or context.

Comment: This is not a matter of "correct". The "correctness" of a definition is rather given by its usability. Similarly, some authors say that $0$ is a natural number and for others $\Bbb N$ starts with $1$. -- Actually, the best definitions are typically those that can be described by many different but equivalent conditions (namely, this equivalence *motivates* the definition); examples of this: "normal subgroup" or "basis of a vector space"